# PHP deleting records on page without deleting in Database

Tags: database

I would like to check whether
if there any ways to delete the record in the page, without deleting records in database?
I'm doing a shopping cart and would like to have the user to be able to view back their past transaction.
Is there any ways that I could delete the records in the cart, after I check out? And also able to view the past transaction.

I've not done any code yet,
just seeking for advices

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can have a database with the products, a second with your users and a third one to associate the users id with the products id they purchased. 
You can never delete a item from the database. You can include a information of status like 'active/inactive' instead of actually deleting it.

***Edit***

When you have products in cart, usually the list is saved in cookies, temporarily by browser or javascript or another way (if your country forbid cookie, you have to search for alternatives). Once the purchase is finished, the cart list is saved in database and the cookie or whatever is cleared. You do not delete anything from database.

**Example**

Users/ buyers database

```
+--------+----------+
| idUser | nameUser |
+--------+----------+
|      1 | Antony   |
|      2 | Betty    |
|      3 | Carl     |
+--------+----------+
```

Products database

```
+-----------+--------------+-------+-----------+
| idProduct | nameProduct  | price | available |
+-----------+--------------+-------+-----------+
|         1 | Apple dozen  | 10.00 | yes       |
|         2 | Banana unity | 20.00 | yes       |
|         3 | Cherry kg    | 30.00 | yes       |
+-----------+--------------+-------+-----------+
```

**Active/ Inactive Example**

Notice here how you don't need to delete any record ever. You can create a option such like `available` to products like example above. So you can just set it to yes or no. So you just code your front-end to show products which available is `yes` while your back-end can see all of them. It is very useful. In a case when your product has tens of information and you delete the product, but it will only be unavailable for 3 weeks, you would lose a great time deleting and typing and saving everything again. It is much better just set it to show or not to show. (Some stores just opt to show everything, but alert when it is unavailable).

Have in mind that it isn't a rule for everything. Always look for the best perfomance. If you have a database with 10k unavaiable products that will never be available again and you just have 2 available itens, it would be a little nosense keep all this records alive.

About prices historic

Prices Historic Database

```
+--------+--------+-----------+-----+----------+----------+
| idItem | idUser | idProduct | qty | subtotal |   date   |
+--------+--------+-----------+-----+----------+----------+
|      1 |      1 |         1 |   2 |       20 | 10/10/13 |
|      2 |      1 |         2 |   1 |       20 | 10/10/13 |
|      3 |      2 |         1 |   1 |       10 | 11/12/13 |
|      4 |      2 |         2 |   1 |       20 | 11/12/13 |
|      5 |      2 |         3 |   1 |       30 | 11/12/13 |
|      6 |      1 |         1 |   1 |       10 | 01/06/14 |
+--------+--------+-----------+-----+----------+----------+
```

It is always good to have a unique identification for each row on database. Well, in most cases. Its is not very readable for humans, but it fits well for machines. Check this database. The line 1 and 2 say us that user 1 bought on 10/10/13 the item with id 1 x 2 and item with id 2 x 1. Translating: Antony bought 2 Apple dozen and 1 Banana unity.

In this database you could filter rows by user and them group by Date. You would see that Antony bought more Apples in 01/06/2014.

I personally like to save the subtotal on database. If in 2015 the apple price raise to 15.00, you and the user can see he paid 10.00 in 2013 and you can do reverse calc to get the individual price.

If you could read this thid database well, you see Betty bought one of each item in 11/12/13 and Carl has never bought anything.

I believe and hope it will help you.

It is just a simplified example on how the logic works. I matched the product directly with buyer, but most stores usually add a 4th database just to list Orders. So you relate Users with Orders and Orders with Products. Everything has its advantages and disadvantages

Comment: HI,, do you have any example on how to do it>?